# What's a better approach to reach to another node that has a common grandparent as the current node?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing, jquery-filter

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <span id="home_location_indicator">(Home)</span>
    </th>
    <td>
        <span class="postal_code_display">...</span>
    </td>
    <td><input value="1" name="location_select" type="radio" /></td>
</tr>
```

Say, I have a `<table>` that contains a couple `<tr>`'s like the one above. Among the `<tr>`'s, there is only one that has `<span id="home_location_indicator">(Home)</span>`.

I am trying to decide on the approach to take for retrieving the *value* of the input `name="location_select"` that belongs to the `<tr>` containing `<span id="home_location_indicator">`.

Here are the two approaches I can think of:

1. `$("tr").has("#home_location_indicator").find('input[name="location_select"]').val()`
2. `$("#home_location_indicator").parents("tr").find('input[name="location_select"]').val()`

Which one is a better approach? And why? Or does it even matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`, because it will stop traversing once it finds a match.

```
$("#home_location_indicator") // ID, very fast
     .closest("tr") // Upwards traversal, fast, stops at tr
     .find(':radio[name="location_select"]').val() // Find, slow-ish
```

This is much better than the top-down approach:

```
$("tr") // getElementsByTagName, very fast
    .has("#home_location_indicator") // traverse EVERY tr ALL the way down, very slow!
    .find('input[name="location_select"]').val() // Find, slow-ish
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach is lot better as it would narrow down the traversing starting from ID and traverse from there.. See below with little modification of what you have,

**Edit:** Using `.closest` is better than `.parents` -> [Proof](http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-parents)

```
$("#home_location_indicator")
     .closest("tr")
     .find(':radio[name="location_select"]').val()
```

The `.has("#home_location_indicator")` in your first approach doesn't make much sense because you are looking for an ID. If you want to get an ID use `$('#IDSelector')` which is the fastest selector because internally it would use `document.getElementByID('IDSelector')`.

Comment: To All Downvoters -> Please leave a reason if you downvote and answer.

Comment: Agree with @SKS. Downvoting without a reason leaves people puzzling and does not help in building a constructive community.